# Printing nested array in columns in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a nested array of values I need to print side by side (in columns) in a Google Sheet. Currently the data stacks when I run my function as shown below.

```
2021-01-14  Thursday    16  0   0   0   2021-01-14T16:15:30.574Z        
2021-01-13  Wednesday   16  260.41  14  18.6    2021-01-14T16:15:30.843Z        
2021-01-07  Thursday    16  332.29  19  17.49   2021-01-14T16:15:31.182Z
```

Nested array (combinedReports)

```
[[2021-01-14, Thursday, 16, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 2021-01-14T16:10:56.571Z], [2021-01-13, Wednesday, 16, 260.41, 14.0, 18.60, 2021-01-14T16:10:56.823Z], [2021-01-07, Thursday, 16, 332.29, 19.0, 17.49, 2021-01-14T16:10:57.012Z]];
```

My printing function

```
  function writeToSheet(data) {
    Logger.log(data);
    //Select the spreadhseet
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    //Get range and export data
    var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
    var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
    //Check there is data to export and run
    if (data.length > 0) {
        sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    } else {
      Logger.log("No data to export.");
    }
  }
  
  writeToSheet(combinedReports);
```

Comment: You need to be more specific on how you are executing your code. This `writeToSheet(combinedReports);` is a **global** call. You **can't** run it separately unless you put it in a **separate function** and run that function itself.

Comment: Thanks - this solves my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your function is fine. I think the issue has to do with your approach.

- The issue is that you have defined the call `writeToSheet(combinedReports);` as a global call and when you execute the only function available which is `writeToSheet` you get an error because `data` is not defined at the time of execution.
- You also haven't defined the `spreadsheet` object.
- If you want to have `writeToSheet(data)` as a separate function, then you need to call it from a separate function. Put `writeToSheet(combinedReports);` in a separate function and call that function instead.

### Solution:

```
function runMe(){ 
  const combinedReports = [['2021-01-14', 'Thursday', 16, 0, 0.0, 0.00, '2021-01-14T16:10:56.571Z'], ['2021-01-13', 'Wednesday', 16, 260.41, 14, 18.6, '2021-01-14T16:10:56.823Z'], ['2021-01-07', 'Thursday', 16, 332.29, 19, 17.49, '2021-01-14T16:10:57.012Z']];    
  writeToSheet(combinedReports);  
}

function writeToSheet(data) {

    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    //Get range and export data
    const last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
    const last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
    const fdata = [data.flat()];
    if (fdata.length > 0) {
        sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, fdata[0].length).setValues(fdata);
    } else {
      Logger.log("No data to export.");
    }
 }
```

Execute only `runMe`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to hardcode your nested array and pass it to your function, and the output is properly placed in columns instead of being stacked:

Sample code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var combinedReports = [['2021-01-14', 'Thursday', 16, 0, 0.0, 0.00, '2021-01-14T16:10:56.571Z'], ['2021-01-13', 'Wednesday', 16, 260.41, 14, 18.6, '2021-01-14T16:10:56.823Z'], ['2021-01-07', 'Thursday', 16, 332.29, 19, 17.49, '2021-01-14T16:10:57.012Z']];
  writeToSheet(combinedReports);
}

function writeToSheet(data) {
  Logger.log(data);
  //Select the spreadhseet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  //Get range and export data
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
    
  //Check there is data to export and run
  if (data.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  } 
  else {
    Logger.log("No data to export.");
  }
}
```

Sample output:

[image]

It is possible that some piece of code outside your function is merging the nested array values before it is passed to `writeToSheet(data)`.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't explain myself properly. The data needs to be spread out in seperate columns. So the first line of data would occupy row 1 and columns A-H and the next line would be row 1, columns I-P and so on.